# Is it possible to position content on the same row as md-tab?

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to place a simple logo img next to a row of tabs, but it seems the default behavior is for the tabs to take up all horizontal space even if it isn't required to display the tabs.  I tried using layout="row" on the containing div, but that made the tabs disappear leaving just the image.  Is it possible?

Edit: In response to @nitin below - Your code does not quite do what I'm asking.  See the picture of your codes results.

[image]

Let me clarify. I'd like the image to be on the same horizontal as the tab buttons, where the red-underlined text is.  Like so:

ONE TWO (some space)  Image

{

(Some tab content)

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work

```
  <md-content class="md-padding">
      <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="one">
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>            
          </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="two">
          <md-content class="md-padding">
            <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>            
          </md-content>
        </md-tab>          
        <md-tab>
          <img src='' alt='image'>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
```

Plunker [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sK70oG?p=preview)

Comment: Hi nitin. Thanks for your answer, but it's not what I was looking for.  Please see my edited question above.